# Encapsulating model in its own class for Angularjs app

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, javascript-objects, angularjs-http

I have 2 views. One is to list student in a table and the other is when you click on a student, it shows the details of the student. I have brought the student to it's own class in a separate file `student.js`. The thing is, student details don't get populated in the view.

I will present the controller and the view for student details along with the student class.

Student prototype as a factory in `student.js`:

```
// idea: You can initialize a student like new Student(student) 
//where student is a json else new Student() will return a student with 
//attributes set to null.

app.factory('Student', ['$http', function($http) {
  function Student(student) {
    if (student) {
        this.setStudent(student);
    } else {
        this.setStudent({
            id: null,
            name: null,
            level: null,
            schoolName: null,
            phoneNumber: null,
            email: null
        });
    }
  };
  Student.prototype = {
    setStudent: function(student) {
        angular.extend(this, student);
    },
    loadStudent: function(studentId) {
        var scope = this;
        $http.get('myUrl/' + studentId).then(function(response){
            scope.setStudent(response.data);
        });
    }
  };
  return Student;
}]);
```

Now I use the Student prototype above in the `studentDetailsCtrl`:

```
app.controller('studentDetailsCtrl', ['$scope', '$stateParams', 'Student', function($scope, $stateParams, Student) {
  $scope.student = new Student();
  $scope.student.loadStudent($stateParams.studentId);
}]);
```

Here `loadStudent()` takes the id of the current student from the url and set the student attributes.

Student Details view:

```
<div ng-controller="studentDetailsCtrl">
<div class="wrapper-md bg-light b-b">
    <h1 class="m-n font-thin h3">Student Details</h1>
</div>
<div class="hbox hbox-auto-xs hbox-auto-sm">
    <div class="col wrapper-md">
        <form name="student" class="form-horizontal">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label col-sm-2">Name: </label>
                <div class="controls col-sm-5">
                    <p class="form-control-static">{{ student.name }}</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

What am I doing wrong? Appreciate any help!

Comment: did you console.log `$scope.student` after `$scope.student = new Student();` ?

Comment: @DMCISSOKHO -  Yeah then I see something like > {id: null, name: null} but when I click on the object to expand I see the name and attribute correctly.

Comment: and if you console.log after `$scope.student.loadStudent($stateParams.studentId);` ?

Comment: @DMCISSOKHO - Exactly the same result. Is it the async get call in `loadStudent()`?

Comment: ok could you post your object here ?

Comment: @DMCISSOKHO - Before expanding: `{id: null, name: null, level: null, schoolName: null, phoneNumber: null, …}` After clicking on the arrow head:`email: "corrineholland@xxxx.xxx"
gender: "female"
id: "57af488efdb597eb035c58a2"
isActive: false
level: "Sec 2"
name: "Corrine Holland"
org_id: 1
phoneNumber: "xxxx xxxxxxx"
schoolName: "strawberry"
status: "archive"`

Comment: try maybe  `$timeout(function(){$scope.student.loadStudent($stateParams.studentId);});`

Comment: @DMCISSOKHO - not working. I get `loadStudent` is not a function error.

Comment: It is not clear what is the current behaviour. Nobody but you can debug the app and make sure that the data is populated properly. A plunker would help. The code you've posted looks fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<form name="student">
```

Creates scope form variable "student" and rewrite your student model.